# Is it possible to use 'where not exists' with the stored procedures...?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
SELECT id INTO @s
        FROM s_menu where name='STUDENTS' LIMIT 1; 
INSERT INTO s_menu (name, mslno, parentid,url,roles) 
    VALUES (studentname, studentmslno, @s,'studentsblank.php',('All,sysadmin,notview'))
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM s_menu WHERE url='studentsblank.php');
```

Comment: What does this have to do with stored procedures? You have the same problem outside of a stored procedure, don't you?

Comment: The problem is with using `WHERE NOT EXISTS` in an `INSERT` query in general.

Comment: Where `studentname` and `studentmslno` values are taken from in `VALUES`? or you mean they're fields of some table?

Answer (score 0):

You may try converting your insert into an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO s_menu (name, mslno, parentid, url, roles)
SELECT studentname, studentmslno, @s, 'studentsblank.php', 'All,sysadmin,notview'
FROM s_menu
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM s_menu WHERE url='studentsblank.php');
```

Here I am assuming that the source of data for the `studentname` and `studentmslno` columns would be the same `s_menu` table which is appearing in the `EXISTS` clause.

Comment: This won't insert anything if `s_menu` is empty. That's why it's better to use `DUAL` as a dummy table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `WHERE` in an `INSERT`, unless it's part of a `SELECT` query.

```
INSERT INTO s_menu (name, mslno, parentid,url,roles) 
SELECT studentname, studentmslno, @s,'studentsblank.php',('All,sysadmin,notview')
FROM DUAL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM s_menu WHERE url='studentsblank.php');
```

Comment: Your answer may not even run if `studentname` and `studentmslno` have not been defined somewhere.  They definitely look to be column names to me.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I believe they're variables in the stored procedure he alluded to.

Comment: I thought it did when you use `WHERE`.

Comment: Barmar what is the use of dual...??

Comment: @ShreyKumar `DUAL` is a fake table that you can use when you need to write a `SELECT` query without reading a table.

Comment: If they're column names, what table are they coming from?